# Entering large string (1 MB) as keyfor a key gives exception

Tags: redis

According to the specification of redis size of the string can be 512 MB ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/HH4z-8mHNLM))

I tried to insert a large string of approximately 1 MB in size using the following command

```
cat command.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

where the content of command.txt is `SET k <large string>`

I am getting following error
   ERR Protocol error: too big inline request

Little bit digging around the net shows that the size of a reuqest is limited by `REDIS_INLINE_MAX_SIZE` whose value is fixed as (1024*64) or 64KB.

Is there any way to change that or is there a better way to send large string into redis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*x-post from /r/redis*](https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/48wrqp/entering_large_string_1_mb_as_keyfor_a_key_gives/d0namuz)

Use one of the many [clients](http://redis.io/clients) - that's the simplest approach.

Alternatively, you can prepare the payload in [RESP](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) and then you won't need even the the cli - for example: https://gist.github.com/itamarhaber/c33ab7a067483050c47d